# How to set goal destination equal to _GET Parameter

Tags: google-analytics

I'm setting up a goal and I have my Goal destination set to:

```
Equals to > /?source=accountCreated
```

My URL is:

```
https://www.example.com/?source=accountCreated
```

But this isn't working. When I run the verification test I get 0%.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is posible with your option:
Are you using a destination as a Objective?
If that is the case you're doing this well.Just check if you parameter is not excluded on the 'Exclude URL Query Parameter', or look for that page on the report.

If this parameter is on that list, remove it or you will never store this parameter.

[image]